# Using PostMessage within a timer in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, timer

I'm trying to create a simple application to turn a PC's monitors on or off depending on the time and day. Using a PostMessage command, I can do this fine, but it seems if I put it in a timer, it fails to work.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Const HWND_BROADCAST As Long = &HFFFF&
    Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Long = &H112&
    Private Const SC_MONITORPOWER As Long = &HF170&
    Private Const POWER_ON = -1
    Private Const POWER_LOW = 1
    Private Const POWER_OFF = 2

    Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal wMsg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Public Sub monitors(ByVal powerState As Integer)
        PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, powerState)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim rightNow As DateTime = DateTime.Now()
        Select Case rightNow.DayOfWeek
            Case 1 To 5
                Label1.Text = "Week day" & vbCrLf & "Auto-power enabled" & vbCrLf & rightNow.Hour & ":" & rightNow.Minute
                If rightNow.Hour >= 17 And rightNow.Minute >= 30 Then
                    monitors(POWER_OFF)
                ElseIf rightNow.Hour >= 8 And rightNow.Minute >= 30 Then
                    monitors(POWER_ON)
                End If
            Case 0 Or 6
                Label1.Text = "Week end" & vbCrLf & "Auto power-off."
                monitors(POWER_OFF)
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        monitors(POWER_OFF)
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is what I'm using; timer is enabled set to an interval of 5000. I thought that perhaps some of the checks the timer does is inadvertently waking the computer instantly, so I've tried putting just the postmessage without luck. The call in button1_click, however, works just fine.

Is this something I'm doing wrong? Is there some sort of security built in to disallow using postmessage/sendmessage in a timer like this?

Comment: You have to start the timer using `timer1.Enabled` before the `timer1.Tick` event will fire.

Comment: @BrandonB: the OP states the timer is enabled.  That could be done via the designer's property pane (e.g. InitializeComponent).